# Debug print Unicode string with \U notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I have a dictionary containing strings with Unicode characters:

```
d = {'middle': "middle is:\U0001f004."}
```

For debugging purposes, I'd like to print `d` and get output with the same notation:

```
print(d)
{'middle': "middle is:\U0001f004."}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3 has the `ascii` function for this purpose.  Any character outside the ASCII character set is displayed as an escape code:

```
>>> d = {'middle': "middle is:\U0001f004."}
>>> d
{'middle': 'middle is:.'}
>>> print(ascii(d))
{'middle': 'middle is:\U0001f004.'}
```

Comment: This is a simple and accurate solution.

Comment: I like how this question was answered by a user who has a gold batch in both Python and Unicode, and who has a profile picture, which is his own name encoded in ASCII :-D

Comment: @XPlatformer you’re the first person to comment on my profile picture. 

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the string representation of the dictionary and encode it using `unicode_escape`. This will return a `bytes` object that you will want to decode again to get a string.

```
d = {'middle': 'middle is:\U0001f004.'}
print(str(d).encode('unicode_escape').decode())
```

Outputs:

```
{'middle': 'middle is:\U0001f004.'}
```

This should work for a wide range of situations but, generally speaking, making sure that the printed string matches the code used to create any data structure is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

When outputing the string, encode it with `unicode_escape`, like this: `string.encode('unicode_escape')`.

Comment: `d` is a dict. A dict does not have an `encode` method.

Comment: Correct, you can only call it on the string. You can use a dict comprehension to call it on every key-value pair in the dict: `{k: v.encode('unicode_escape') for k, v in d.items()}`.

Comment: this won't work for a list then. Or a dict of dicts. I need something more generic. Debugging stuff with unicode strings in.

Comment: ...then I get `b"{'middle': 'middle is:\\U0001f004.'}"`. What I asked for was `{'middle': 'middle is:\U0001f004.'}`. Still some way to go... All I need is an easy way to debug-print some variables in my code.

Comment: At last we know you are using Python3!